# how to pass equation variable as a feature vector to a training classifier in python

Tags: python, vector, classification, feature-extraction

I'm using few equations as centroid skewness and kurtosis to extract features from images how to pass the return of each variable as one feature vector to the classifier

"feature.append(image_statistics(img))"

def image_statistics(img)

```
cx = np.sum(x*xp)/np.sum(xp)
cy = np.sum(y*yp)/np.sum(yp)

x2 = (x-cx)**2
y2 = (y-cy)**2

sx = np.sqrt( np.sum(x2*xp)/np.sum(xp) )
sy = np.sqrt( np.sum(y2*yp)/np.sum(yp) )

x3 = (x-cx)**3
y3 = (y-cy)**3

skx = np.sum(xp*x3)/(np.sum(xp) * sx**3)
sky = np.sum(yp*y3)/(np.sum(yp) * sy**3)

x4 = (x-cx)**4
y4 = (y-cy)**4
kx = np.sum(xp*x4)/(np.sum(xp) * sx**4)
ky = np.sum(yp*y4)/(np.sum(yp) * sy**4)

return  cx + y + sx + sy + skx + sky + kx + ky
```

Answer (score 0):

Would append every variable to a `dict` and return the `dict` solve your problem?

```
vector_ref = ['cx', 'y', 'sx', 'sy', 'skx', 'sky', 'kx', 'ky']
vector_val = [cx, y, sx, sy, skx, sky, kx, ky]
return_dict = dict(zip(vector_ref, vector_val))

return (return_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'cx': cx, 'y': y, 'sx': sx, 'sy': sy, 'skx': skx, 'sky': sky, 'kx': kx, 'ky': ky}
```